# Wordpress custom post-type pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a section at the bottom of my wordpress page that should display a group of posts (custom post type), 9 at a time, with simple pagination to scroll to the next/prev 9.

This is my code so far:

```
    <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby'=> 'event_date',
        'meta_key'=>'event_date',
        'meta_query' => array(array('key'=>'event_date', 'value'=>date('Y-m-d'))),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'paged'=>$paged
     )) ?> 

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <article class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <h2 class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <h3 class="date_posted sub_text"><?php echo date('l, F jS', strtotime(get_field('event_date'))); ?></h3>
                <?php html5wp_excerpt('events_page_listing'); ?>
                <a class=lead_in href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a>                   
            </article>

    <?php  endwhile; ?>

    <div><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
    <div><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
```

I don't completely understand the paging process and I've taken this code from snippets found on some forums but it's not working. Currently, with this setup above, it's just showing two of the posts, with no pagination.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or identify what I'm missing?

Comment: did you get your post without pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following : -

change this line :-

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

to

```
if (get_query_var('paged')):
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif (get_query_var('page')):
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
else:
    $paged = 1;
endif;
```

My article on this http://codenathan.com/wordpress/pagination-on-wordpress-page

Comment: I tried this but it still just shows the first two posts in the loop (with no pagination). I looked with Firebug and see the pagination divs are completely empty also.

Answer (score 0):

The `'compare'` index should be inserted in the field array within the meta_query.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby'=> 'event_date',
        'meta_key'=>'event_date',
        'meta_query' => 
            array(
                array( 
                    'key'=>'event_date', 
                    'value'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                    'compare' => '>='
                )
            ),
        'paged'=>$paged
     ) 
);
```

Fore reference: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Hope it helps :  )